# select max(Date) from table always returns 1970-01-01

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am trying to select the max date using the ORMLITE lib:

```
 GenericRawResults<Object[]> result = null;

    try {
        String sql = "select MAX(t.last_updated_on_server_utc) from measurements t";

        result = databaseManager.getMeasurementDao().queryRaw(
                sql, new DataType[]{DataType.DATE_LONG}
        );
        List<Object[]> results = result.getResults();
        if (results.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Date d = (Date) results.get(0)[0];
//                Date d = new Date((Long) results.get(0)[0]);
            Log.d(TAG, "d=" + d);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
```

The date returned is always 1970-01-01 (i.e the value of d in the debug output)...That field is declared as a java.util.Date. I also tried using DataType.LONG, and still the same. If I use a raw query to select one of the date columns it's fine, my problem is when I use MAX().

Comment: SQLite has no built-in date data type. In what format are the dates stored in the database?

Comment: In the domain object the date is declared as Date. ORMLite takes care of defining the datatype of the table, which in this case should be Integer. See: http://ormlite.com/data_types.shtml, https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html